# Sort subdirectory names downloaded from within them

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, filenames

I have a directory, I sort the names of its subdirectories. But these are numerical names (plant identification numbers). I would like to have the plant names displayed rather than their ID numbers. In each subdirectory I have a txt file containing the name of the plant. I display it in the menu next to the plant ID number. But I would like to have the plant names (not ID!!) sorted in ascending order.

The file with the plant name has a title >> "id plant"_info_01c.txt <<

$taxon = ID Plant = name of subdirectory

The name of the plant >> $file_info_01c_text << is a link to iframe.

I would like to ask for the simplest possible solution for possible repair by a novice in the times of fallout. If a database is needed, it should only be in txt.

```
<?php

$path = ".";
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        
        $taxon = $fileinfo->getFilename();
        $file_info_01c = $taxon.'/'.$taxon.'_info_01c.txt';
        // wczytanie pliku 'info_01c.txt'
        $file_info_01c_text = file_get_contents($file_info_01c);

        echo $taxon.' &nbsp;  <A href="index-if.php?taxon='.$taxon.'" target="ramka">'.$file_info_01c_text.'</A><br>';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: PSA: PHP does [interpolate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) so you don't need to mess around with concatenation here. `"$x.{$y}_z"` is a lot less messy than `$x.'.'.$y.'_z'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your data to an array and sort it before you echo the link.

```php
$plants = [];

foreach (new DirectoryIterator(".") as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        $taxon = $fileinfo->getFilename();
        $plants[] = [
            'name'  => file_get_contents("{$taxon}/{$taxon}_info_01c.txt"),
            'taxon' => $taxon,
        ];
    }
}

// Sort results by the file text
usort($plants, fn($a, $b) => $a['name'] <=> $b['name']);

// Create the links here instead
foreach ($plants as $plant) {
    $name  = $plant['name'];
    $taxon = $plant['taxon'];
    echo "{$taxon} &nbsp; <a href=\"index-if.php?taxon={$taxon}\" target=\"ramka\">{$name}</a><br>";
}
```

Comment: That isn't an associative array, it is an indexed array containing associative rows.

Comment: In a modern PHP application, use arrow functiins and the spaceship operator (if not using `array_multisort()`).  This answer also has too many single-use variable declarations and could be refined more.

Comment: Updated with suggestions.